# Laravel request remove fields before validation

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-request

I am trying to remove some fields before they are validated.
Trying to attempt this inside prepareForValidation()

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class VideoRequest extends ApiRequest
{

    // ..code..

    protected function prepareForValidation()
    {
        $this->merge([
            'public' => $this->toBoolean($this->public),
            'notify' => $this->toBoolean($this->notify),
        ]);

        $video_id = $this->route('video_id');
        if($this->isMethod('put') && Video::salesStarted($video_id)){
            Log::info('removing sales');
            // attempt 1
            $this->except(['sales_start', 'tickets', 'price']);
            // attempt 2
            $this->request->remove('sales_start');
            // attempt 3
            $this->offsetUnset('sales_start');
        }
        if($this->isMethod('put') && Video::streamStarted($video_id)){
            Log::info('removing streams');
            // attempt 1
            $this->except(['stream_start', 'stream_count', 'archive']);
            // attempt 2
            $this->request->remove('sales_start');
            // attempt 3
            $this->offsetUnset('sales_start');
        }
        
        $thumb = $this->uploadThumbnail($video_id);
        if($thumb !== null){
            $this->merge($thumb);
        }
    }

    // ..code..

}
```

I made sure the code was entering inside the `if` statement, however the fields are not being removed.
Running `$this->request->remove()` and `$this->except()` have no effect.
If I add `safe()` it throws `Call to a member function safe() on null`. 
I also tried to use `unset()` but nothing seems to work.
The rules for the dates are like so:

```
'sales_start' => 'sometimes|required|date|after:now|before:stream_start',
'stream_start' => 'sometimes|required|date|after:now',
```

but the `$request->validated()` returns the errors although it shouldn't be validating the deleted fields.

```
"sales_start": [
    "The sales start must be a date after now."
],
"stream_start": [
    "The stream start must be a date after now."
]
```

Why are the fields not being deleted?

### Edit

As requested I added some code.
This is what ApiRequest looks like:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;

abstract class ApiRequest extends FormRequest
{
    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator): void
    {
        $response['data']    = [];
        $response['api_status']  = 'ng';
        $response['status_message'] = 'failed validation';
        $response['errors']  = $validator->errors()->toArray();

        throw new HttpResponseException(
            response()->json( $response, 422 )
        );
    }

    protected function toBoolean($booleable)
    {
        return filter_var($booleable, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

And the request is called from the controller like so:

```
public function update(VideoRequest $request, $video_id)
{
    ... some code ...

    $validated = $request->validated();

    ... some code ...
}
```

so `$this` refers to the VideoRequest that extends FormRequest.

Comment: Do you use `$request->all()` to validate?

Comment: Why are you going to delete fields of request while you can exclude fields that you need?

Comment: @geertjanknapen No, I use ```$request->validated()```

Comment: @Sahand Moghadam I am fine with either deleting or excluding. I tried both, both didn't work. (I tried ```$request->except()```). Or are you referring to another method?

Comment: Let's just stick to ` $this->request->remove('sales_start');` method. please take it out from all if statements and check whether it is working. besides, `$request->validated()` is responsible for returning fields that the validation rules have validated.

Comment: I tried taking the code out of all if statements, but nothing changed. As far as I know ```$request->validated()``` should not be validating the field if it were removed successfully, because of ```sometimes|required``` @Sahand Moghadam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the above is really correct, but the following will work.

In protected function `prepareForValidation()`, you can do something like this:

```
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
   $input = $this->input();

   unset($input['my_key']);

   $this->replace($input);
}
```

That will let you change and replace data before it's validated.

Of course you can also `collect()` the `$this->input()` data before working with it, if you prefer to work with a collection.

Comment: Altho I no longer have the project to try out the code, I think the issue was that I was not using the ```replace()```. For example when using except the code should be written like this ```$request->replace($request->except('my_key'));```, probably because ```$request->except()``` just returns its value without modifying the request itself :/

Answer (score 1):

Can't find anything about deleting. But acording to [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#retrieving-a-portion-of-the-input-data) you pick what keys you need from a request as follows:

```
$request->only(['username', 'password']);
// plug everything you need into the array.
$request->except(['username', 'password']);
//plug everything you don't need into the array
```

The latter is probably most useful to you.

Example:

Say I have the following keys: `['username', 'password', 'randomVal'];`

```
$request->only(['username', 'password']);
// Output:
['username', 'password']

$request->except(['username', 'password']);
// Output:
['randomVal']
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried this (in the commented out code). For some reason it is not having any effect.

Comment: What is `$this`, usually it refers to the calling object, so how does it (in your case) refer to the request? Can you show some more code.

Comment: I added the code to the original comment

Comment: So if this refers to an instance of `FormRequest` how do you see it removing keys? `FormRequest` is not the same as `Request` try using `$request` instead of `$this` for me..

Comment: ```FormRequest``` extends ```Request``` so it actually is "the same" ([docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.html)). And using ```$this->``` inside the request should be the same as using ```$request->```. I also tested out ```$request```, but unfortunately nothing changed.

Comment: For reference I tried using ```$request``` inside the controller, so I put ```$request->except([...stuff...])``` right before ```$request->validated```.

Comment: Well if its a `Request` then `->except([...])` and `->only([...])` should work.. are you missing something else?

Comment: I don't think I'm missing anything, since other methods such as ```merge()```are working fine. I will later on try and removing some codes from the ```VideoRequest``` to see if something was interfering.

Answer (score 1):

To remove (unset) a key from a `Request` before it goes to the Controller you can use [offsetUnset()](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Http/Client/Request.html#method_offsetUnset)
inside your request:

```
 protected function prepareForValidation()
    {
        $this->offsetUnset('sales_start');//same goes for the other key to remove...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this as well, but for some reason it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the request before the validation, I tried adding exclude when getting `rules()`.
So something along these lines:

```
public function rules() {
    $ex = $this->isMethod('put') && Video::salesStarted($video_id) ? 'exclude|' : '';
    return [
        'sales_start' => $ex.'sometimes|required|other_stuff',
    ];
}
```

Note that the validation 'exclude' only works if added first.
So this won't work:

```
'sometimes|required|other_stuff|exclude' //exclude is called last
```

**EDIT**
The reason why `remove(), exclude(), offsetUnset()` were not working was that they return the value of the modified request without actually modifying the request.
So the right way to use them would be as follows:

```
// this removes sales_start from the request
$request->replace($request->except('sales_start'));
```